# TypeError: normalize() argument 2 must be str, not Series with a dataframe of strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, nltk, typeerror

I have a dataframe that contains news for each day and I try to analyze the intensity of the feeling for the day, it is to say if the general feeling of the day from the news is positive, negative or neutral. Here is the `df_news` dataframe :

```
    Date    name
0   2017-10-20  Gucci debuts art installation at its Ginza sto...
1   2018-08-01  Gucci Joins Paris Fashion Week for Its Spring ...
2   2018-04-20  Gucci launches its new creative hub Gucci ArtL...
3   2017-10-20  Gucci to launch homeware line Gucci Decor - CP...
4   2017-12-07  GUCCI opens new store at Miami Design District...
5   2018-01-12  Gucci opens Gucci Garden in Florence - LUXUO
6   2018-02-26  GUCCI's wild experiment with the Fall Winter 2...
7   2018-08-09  Gucci Revamped London Flagship Store | The Imp...
8   2018-08-01  Alessandro Michele Announces new Gucci Home co...
9   2017-10-20  Before He Picks Up the CFDA’s International Aw...
```

I tried to get the intensity of the feeling with the following code he uses [`SentimentIntensityAnalyzer`](https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.sentiment.html#nltk.sentiment.vader.SentiText) de [`nltk.sentiment.vader`](https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.sentiment.html#module-nltk.sentiment.vader)  :

```
from nltk.sentiment.vader import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer
import unicodedata
sid = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()
for date, row in df_news.T.iteritems():
    try:
        sentence = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', df_news.loc[date, 'name']).encode('ascii','ignore')
        #print((sentence))
        ss = sid.polarity_scores(str(sentence))
        df_news.set_value(date, 'compound', ss['compound'])
        df_news.set_value(date, 'neg', ss['neg'])
        df_news.set_value(date, 'neu', ss['neu'])
        df_news.set_value(date, 'pos', ss['pos'])
    except TypeError:
        print(df_news.loc[date, 'name'])
        print(date)
```

However I get a TypeError for certain dates. Thanks to `try catch` you do not take it into account and draw the following table :

```
    name    compound    neg neu pos
Date                    
2017-10-20  Gucci debuts art installation at its Ginza sto...               
2018-08-01  Gucci Joins Paris Fashion Week for Its Spring ...               
2018-04-20  Gucci launches its new creative hub Gucci ArtL...   0.4404  0   0.756   0.244
2017-10-20  Gucci to launch homeware line Gucci Decor - CP...               
2017-12-07  GUCCI opens new store at Miami Design District...   0   0   1   0
2018-01-12  Gucci opens Gucci Garden in Florence - LUXUO    0   0   1   0
2018-02-26  GUCCI's wild experiment with the Fall Winter 2...   0   0   1   0
2018-08-09  Gucci Revamped London Flagship Store | The Imp...   0.3182  0   0.602   0.398
2018-08-01  Alessandro Michele Announces new Gucci Home co...               
2017-10-20  Before He Picks Up the CFDA’s International Aw...
```

But when I delete try catch to understand why it failed, I get the following error :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-2e9dbfc62bce> in <module>
      4 for date, row in df_news.T.iteritems():
      5 #    try:
----> 6     sentence = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', df_news.loc[date, 'name']).encode('ascii','ignore')
      7     #print((sentence))
      8     ss = sid.polarity_scores(str(sentence))

TypeError: normalize() argument 2 must be str, not Series
```

Then I thought that the problem was with the lines that were not string but for example with the first :

```
>>>type(df_news['name'][0])
str
```

#### To get the data

```
doc_data = {
  "size": 10,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must" : [
       {"term":{"text":"gucci"}}
     ]
    }
  }
 }

docs = create_doc("https://elastic:rKzWu2WbXI@db.luxurynsight.com/luxurynsight_v2/news/_search",doc_data)


information_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(docs.json()["hits"]["hits"])

# Reading the JSON file
df_news = pd.read_json('data.json')

# Converting the element wise _source feature datatype to dictionary
df_news._source = df_news._source.apply(lambda x: dict(x))

# Creating name column
df_news['name'] = df_news._source.apply(lambda x: x['name'])

# Creating createdAt column
df_news['createdAt'] = df_news._source.apply(lambda x: x['createdAt'])

df_news['createdAt'] =  pd.to_datetime(df_news['createdAt'], unit='ms')

df_news['createdAt'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df_news.createdAt).normalize()
#df_news.createdAt.dt.normalize()

df_news['Date'] = df_news['createdAt']

df_news = df_news[['name','Date']]
df_news = df_news.set_index('Date')
information_df._source = information_df.apply(lambda x: dict(x))
df_news.reset_index()
```

It should give back :

```
    Date    name
0   2017-10-20  Gucci debuts art installation at its Ginza sto...
1   2018-08-01  Gucci Joins Paris Fashion Week for Its Spring ...
2   2018-04-20  Gucci launches its new creative hub Gucci ArtL...
3   2017-10-20  Gucci to launch homeware line Gucci Decor - CP...
4   2017-12-07  GUCCI opens new store at Miami Design District...
5   2018-01-12  Gucci opens Gucci Garden in Florence - LUXUO
6   2018-02-26  GUCCI's wild experiment with the Fall Winter 2...
7   2018-08-09  Gucci Revamped London Flagship Store | The Imp...
8   2018-08-01  Alessandro Michele Announces new Gucci Home co...
9   2017-10-20  Before He Picks Up the CFDA’s International Aw...
```

## Edit :

I grouped the articles that appears the same days and put in lists the articles

```
# get date out of the index to column    
df_news = df_news.reset_index()
# optional
df_news['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_news['Date'])
# groupby and output group rows as list
df_news = df_news.groupby('Date')['name'].apply(list)
df_news.head()
```

It gives me back :

```
Date
2017-10-20    [Gucci debuts art installation at its Ginza st...
2017-12-07    [GUCCI opens new store at Miami Design Distric...
2018-01-12       [Gucci opens Gucci Garden in Florence - LUXUO]
2018-02-26    [GUCCI's wild experiment with the Fall Winter ...
2018-04-20    [Gucci launches its new creative hub Gucci Art...
2018-08-01    [Gucci Joins Paris Fashion Week for Its Spring...
2018-08-09    [Gucci Revamped London Flagship Store | The Im...
Name: name, dtype: object
```

Therefore when I try to apply Stael's answer :

```
sentence = df_news.loc[date, 'name'].apply(lambda x: unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', x).encode('ascii','ignore'))
```

That is to say to normalize to each item in the series

I get the following error :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexingError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-173-1bc93a0a065c> in <module>
      5     try:
      6         #sentence = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', df_news.loc[date, 'name']).encode('ascii','ignore')
----> 7         sentence = df_news.loc[date, 'name'].apply(lambda x: unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', x).encode('ascii','ignore'))
      8         ss = sid.polarity_scores(str(sentence))
      9         df_news.set_value(date, 'compound', ss['compound'])

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   1470             except (KeyError, IndexError):
   1471                 pass
-> 1472             return self._getitem_tuple(key)
   1473         else:
   1474             # we by definition only have the 0th axis

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _getitem_tuple(self, tup)
    873 
    874         # no multi-index, so validate all of the indexers
--> 875         self._has_valid_tuple(tup)
    876 
    877         # ugly hack for GH #836

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _has_valid_tuple(self, key)
    218         for i, k in enumerate(key):
    219             if i >= self.obj.ndim:
--> 220                 raise IndexingError('Too many indexers')
    221             try:
    222                 self._validate_key(k, i)

IndexingError: Too many indexers
```

And when I try to only take `Date` in the Index I got sentence = `df_news.loc[date].aply(x: ...` :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-176-308d1f6c6644> in <module>
      5     try:
      6         #sentence = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', df_news.loc[date, 'name']).encode('ascii','ignore')
----> 7         sentence = df_news.loc[date].apply(lambda x: unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', x).encode('ascii','ignore'))
      8         ss = sid.polarity_scores(str(sentence))
      9         df_news.set_value(date, 'compound', ss['compound'])

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'apply'
```

Answer (score 0):

it looks to me like it is this line:

```
sentence = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', df_news.loc[date, 'name']).encode('ascii','ignore')
```

you're trying to call normalise on each item in the series df.news.loc[...]

but pandas doesn't apply the function across the series for you - I think what you want to do is something like this:

```
sentence = df_news.loc[date, 'name'].apply(lambda x: unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', x).encode('ascii','ignore')
```

which is the pandas way of applying a function (normalize) to each item in a series.

---

Edit:

Theory 2 - when you call `df_news.loc[date, 'name']` you are selecting the item where `index==date` and `column=='name'` - but it looks from your question that some of the date's are duplicated in your index, which means that sometimes instead of getting a single record where you can call `unicodedata.normalize` on it, you are getting a series, which causes your error.

you'll notice that the records that didn't fill when you used the 'try: except:` clause are records which have duplicated dates.

you need to handle that in some way, perhaps by using `row` out of iteritems rather than date, but that's for you to figure out.

Comment: Hmm it then create a `SyntaxError: invalid syntaxe` on `ss = sid.polarity_scores(str(sentence))`

Comment: what are you expecting the variable sentence to be? you're operating on a series in the first case, so you would expect something like a series to come out of it - you can't take str or a series, it wouldn't make sense.

Comment: Sorry !! I had a missing parenthesis, the actual error is `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'apply'` on `df_news.loc[date, 'name'].apply(lambda ...`

Comment: ok, i think i'm starting to understand - I think that `df_news.loc[date, 'name']` is sometimes giving you a string and sometimes giving you a `Series`. I see from your question that the date `'2017-10-20'` appears twice in the index. In that case you would get a series rather than a string. You need to handle that somehow before you can `normalize` it. (I think)

Comment: @ThePassenger I've edited my answer to try to make it clearer.

Comment: Haa, I'm not sure it's duplicates I thought it articles written the same day. Thought making an array for each row/day.

Comment: @ThePassenger - i don't mean they are duplicate rows, i mean when you do `df_news.loc['2017-10-20', 'name']` you return multiple rows, because `'2017-10-20'` is duplicated in your index. Because it is multiple rows it is a `Series` object (rather than a `str`) so your code crashes.

Answer (score 0):

seeing as you have moved on to a 3rd error on the one post I thought I'll have one more go at this.

First and foremost I feel like you don't understand a lot of your own code. errors like `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'apply'` imply to me that you don't know what your variable are when you are operating on them, so I think you need to work more slowly and carefully to understand what each bit of your code is doing before you move on to the next section.

That said, your problem isn't as complicated as you have made it - you are trying to apply these two lines of code

```
    sentence = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', df_news.loc[date, 'name']).encode('ascii','ignore')

    ss = sid.polarity_scores(str(sentence))
```

to every entry in the column 'name' in your dataframe, which is not that hard.

you could do it as easily as this:

```
scores = []
for entry in df['name']:
    sentence = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', entry).encode('ascii','ignore')
    scores.append(sid.polarity_scores(str(sentence)))
```

that will give you a list of the score dictionaries you were calling `ss`

you can apply those as columns in your dataframe like this:

```
df['new_column'] = [i['example_key'] for i in scores]
```

it's not the best or most efficient way of doing it, but it is a pretty simple way for you to achieve what it looks like you're trying to do.

Good luck.

---

if you have previously grouped by day, and listed your strings (btw I don't think you should do that) then you need another layer of iteration

```
scores = []
for sentence_list in df['name']:
    for entry in sentence_list:
        sentence = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', entry).encode('ascii','ignore')
        scores.append(sid.polarity_scores(str(sentence)))
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Yet I still have a `TypeError` with `sentence = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', entry).encode('ascii','ignore')` because entry is a list. However when I do `sentence = df_news.loc[date, 'name']` I can apply `ss = sid.polarity_scores(str(sentence))` on some sentence, the other seems not to work as far as the returned score for `neu` is 1.

Comment: I don't think there is any reason for you to have grouped the strings into a list. I think you did that because you had duplicates in the date index, but that isn't really a problem - this approach should work with duplicate dates just fine.